# Inheritance in Python with Different Argument(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

When a subclass inherits from a superclass, must the subclass have all the arguments that the superclass has? E.g.: "Vehicle(colour, wheels, size)" is the superclass. Can I have a subclass that inherits everything from Vehicle except the "size" attribute/argument?

## This is the parent class:

```
class LagStudent:

    def __init__(self, name, dept, cgpa, is_a_scholar):
        self.name = name
        self.dept = dept
        self.cgpa = cgpa
        self.is_a_scholar = is_a_scholar
```

## Below are two subclasses:

```
class CovStudent(LagStudent):

    def __init__(self, name, dept, cgpa, is_a_scholar, honours):
        super().__init__(name, dept, cgpa, is_a_scholar)
        self.honours = honours


class OxStudent(CovStudent):

    def __init__(self, name, dept, cgpa, is_a_scholar):
        super().__init__(name, dept, cgpa, is_a_scholar)
```

## When I run the following...

```
student4 = OxStudent("Mark", "Mathematics", 4.62, True)
print(student4.is_a_scholar)
```

## It gives Error:

TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'honours'

Comment: The question is not clear: how should subclass methods behave then? They can't call parent `Vehicle` methods as they require `size` as arg.

Comment: If you are talking only about object initialisation then the answer is yes, you can have `SubVehicle(Vehicle)` with `__init__(colour, wheels)` overridden that sets `self.size` to some neccesary value.

Comment: Yes of course you *can*. The question is, *should you?*

Comment: Why does `OxStudent` inherit from `CovStudent` here and not `LagStudent`?

Comment: "Can I have a subclass that inherits everything from Vehicle except the "size" attribute/argument?" - no. This would be a definitely bad design. Please read about the Liskov substitution principle. "It is based on the concept of "substitutability" – a principle in object-oriented programming stating that an object (such as a class) may be replaced by a sub-object (such as a class that extends the first class) without breaking the program." (Wikipedia) A subclass of A is "kind of A", and you should expect it to have all properties and methods of A (maybe some more, but it's not that important).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We define the Vehicle superclass as follows, and Bicycle subclass as follows

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, colour, wheels, size):

        self.colour = colour
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.size = size

class Cycle(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self, colour, wheels, size):

        super().__init__(colour, wheels, 'small')
```

Here you can see that the Cycle subclass just takes in `colors` and `wheels` and passes it onto the superclass, and has a hardcoded `size=small` attribute. The subclass constructor calls the constructor of the superclass

To check what's going on, we can try as follows:

```
veh = Cycle('Black', 2)
print(veh.colour)
print(veh.wheels)
print(veh.size)
#Black
#2
#small
```

**Update**
Based on OP's comment of not wanting to have a size attribute, you can assign a default value to the size attribute in the superclass, e.g. `size=None` and you won't need to pass it while instantiating the subclass.

```
class Vehicle:

    def __init__(self, colour, wheels, size=None):

        self.colour = colour
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.size = size

class Cycle(Vehicle):

    def __init__(self, colour, wheels):

        super().__init__(colour, wheels)
```

You can then call this as follows

```
veh = Cycle('Black', 2)
print(veh.colour)
print(veh.wheels)
print(veh.size)
#Black
#2
#None
```

You can see that the value of `size` is `None`, which is the default value we picked since we did not pass `size` explicitly, if we would have passed it, we would have got a value for the `size` attribute

Comment: Ok, so what I mean is: What if I don't want the Cycle to have a "size" attribute. Is it possible to omit it when constructing the class, or is it compulsory that I include it even if I don't want instances of that class to possess the "size" attribute?

Comment: Okay I have updated my answer to include that scenario!

Comment: This is what I mean. The issue now is that the program doesn't run. It gives this error: in __init__ super().__init__(colour, wheels) TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'size'

Comment: Can you show which class are you instantiating and how are you instantiating it

Comment: I've edited my original question. Please see whether you get what I mean. Thanks.

Comment: You are inherenting OxStudent from CovStudent which has an attribute honours. So you have to provide a default value for honours in CovStudent, unless you wanted both OxStudent and CovStudent to inherit from LagStudent

Comment: I just thought it should be possible to have a subclass that may not necessarily inherit every single attribute of the parent class. So what I now understand is: If I want to create a class B that has maybe 8 out of 10 attributes of another class A, I cannot make B a subclass of A; I will have to define B completely as a separate (parent) class of its own?

Comment: You can obviously do that, and for the 2 attributes, just use a default value in the constructor, like I did for size argument in Vehicle class

Comment: Ok, I think I get you now. Thanks. Will mark your answer. Cheers.

Comment: Great! Finally :)

Comment: "Based on OP's comment of not wanting to have a size attribute, you can assign a default value to the size attribute in the superclass, e.g. size=None". 1) don't do that. That violates the Liskov substitution principle. 2) you actually have the *size* attribute (which is just *None*). This is very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

A subclass certainly can have a different signature for the `__init__` method from its superclass. It just needs to call the `__init__` method of its superclass with what that method expects:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, colour, wheels, size):
        self.colour = colour
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.size = size

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, colour, wheels):
        super().__init__(colour, wheels, 'small')

print(Car('white', 4).size)
```

This outputs:

```
small
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what I really want to know is: What if I don't want the "Car" class to have a "size" attribute? Is it possible to omit it in both the class construction and inheritance initialisation?

Comment: @Goriola, then it's not really a subclass, is it?